# Remotely calculating SHA or MD5 of a file via web service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, md5

For example.. say I have an application that uses a web service. I want the application to consume the web service, which basically just calculates the MD5 or SHA-whatever of the consuming application.

What's the best way to achieve this? The consuming application is ~10kb.

Comment: md5/sha is calculated on a chunk of bytes, not a "service".

Comment: I want the calculation to reside in the service, but calculate a remote file.

Comment: you can't calculate on a remote file, unless that remote site provides a service which does the calculation for you. You'll have to un-remote the file, e.g. fetch a copy to wherever your service is running and do the calcs there.

Comment: It seems @user1201320 wants its client application upload itself to a web service which returns the checksum for the uploaded file(s).

Comment: That's exactly what I'm after, I'm just poor at explaining what's in my head.

Comment: I don't understand why the client can't calculate its checksum itself. If this is for protection against tampering, it's non-effective, because a cracked client can simply upload the original file(s).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do it:

```
var request  = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("http://www.remote.com/file");
var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
var hasher = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
foreach (byte b in hasher.ComputeHash(stream))
    hash += b.ToString("x2").ToLower();
```

Obviously wrap that up in using's appropriate to keep resources under control.

Comment: I'll play around with this. Thanks!